# Passing a username from django login to angular navbar

Tags: django, angular

I am using django login template as the first page a user will see, upon successful login they will then be on the angular side because of the `<app-root>` tag in my django home template. I have a navbar component in angular and I would like to display the users name and give them an option to logout.

I can see it is getting the name correctly as it shows if I have it before the `<app-root>` tag. I am currently trying to pass `{{user.username}}` into the `<app-root>` tag and then eventually through to the navbar component but nothing appears on the navbar.

Django Template:

```
{{user.username}} //this bit shows the correct name

<app-root [theUser] = "{{user.username}}">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <div class="spinner-border p-5 m-5" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading . . .</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</app-root>
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-nav-bar [theUserName]="theUser"></app-nav-bar>
```

nav-bar.component.html:

```
<h4>{{theUserName}}</h4>
```

I expected the username to be passed through the angular components and be displayed on the navbar. There is nothing being displayed, I can see the h4 is empty on dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be changed

```
  <app-root [theUser] = "{{user.username}}">
```

to:

```
  <app-root [theUser] = "user.username">
```

Comment: the h4 tag is still empty in the navbar, could this be something to do with curly brackets being in both django and angular?